# Possible problems if using XBee API mode communication using Java and C on each endpoint

Tags: java, c, libraries, xbee

I am wondering if any problems may arise, when implementing a XBee point to point link using API mode if one is programmed using the Java XBee libraries and the other Ansi C libraries on a microcontroller.

An API frame is an API frame but still.. I only need API mode to use the ACK and encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problems will arise, and you can even operate each XBee at a different baud rate.  A module in API mode can communicate with a module running in "AT mode" (or transparent serial).  A module in API mode 1 communicates just fine with API mode 2.  Different `ATAO` settings affect local communications only.

The options you select are solely for local communication between host and XBee module.  That module then communicates with remote modules over the 802.15.4 network, and the receiving module sends data out to the host in whatever format is dictated by the local configuration.